# Is it better to redirect an entire site (wordpress) using a plugin or using the hosting company (godaddy)

Tags: wordpress, redirect, forwarding

I have a new site and domain that I would like my old site to redirect to. My question is, what's faster/better. Use goDaddy's url forwarding or a wordpress plugin to forward the traffic. My assumption would be that the goDaddy may be a bit faster. Any opinions?

Comment: I would say use your domain provider (godaddy) to instantly forward your old site domain to the new one. Then you can at least have access to the old site if you want by locating it on a sub domain http://oldsite.newdomain.com or something like that.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot!